# Let $E$ be an idempotent matrix different from the identity, then $\det(E) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, nilpotence, idempotents

I have seen the following theorem on the book of *Linear Algebra* by Cemal Koç, and gave a counterexample, but this book is used as the main textbook for linear algebra courses in my university, so I'm assuming I'm missing something.

> Let $E$ be an idempotent matrix different from the identity, then
>   $\det(E) = 0$

**CounterExample:**

Let $F$ be a field with at least 2 idempotent element $q$ and $p$, then define 
$$E = \begin{bmatrix} q & 0\\0 & p\end{bmatrix}$$, so $$E^2 = \begin{bmatrix} q^2 & 0\\0 & p^2\end{bmatrix}$$ and $\det(E) \not = 0$.

Comment: It would be a useful exercise to prove that in any field, the only idempotent elements are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is an idempotent element of a field. Then $p^2 = p$, so
$p(p - 1) = 0$. This forces $p = 0$ or $p = 1$.  This vitiates your counterexample.

Comment: Today I learned that "vitiate" is a word

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah, me too :)

Answer (score 4):

The idempotent elements in a field are exactly $0$ and $1$.

Therefore, $\det E= 0$.

To answer the question in the title:

If $E^2=E$, then let $d=\det E$. Then $d^2=d$ and so $d=0$ or $d=1$.

If $d=1$, then $E$ is invertible and $E^2=E$ implies $E=I$.

Therefore, if $E\ne I$, then $d\ne 1$ and so $d=0$.